# What is this type of question called? "I can have a cookie, can't I?"

Tags: grammar, american-english, questions, question-tags

> I can have a cookie, can't I?

What is this type of question called?

Also, is it grammatically correct under American English?

Comment: I don't know what it's called, but it is a common (and grammatically correct) formulation of the question. It's kind of asking for permission, i.e. the negative "can't I" indicates the questioner doesn't want to presume.

Answer (score 4):

That's called a **[tag question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question)**.

As far as I know, it's grammatically correct in many variants of English, American English included.

> A question tag or tag question (also known as tail question) is a grammatical structure in which a declarative statement or an imperative is turned into a question by adding an interrogative fragment (the "tag"). **For example**, in the sentence "You're John, aren't you?", the statement "You're John" is turned into a question by the tag "aren't you".

(My emphasis.)

Comment: Could you provide a summary from the link?

Comment: Thanks.
It won't let me up vote this answer unless I have 15 rep.